# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js

a simple method is throwing me syntax error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

```
module.exports.verifyStandardMetadata(data) => {
  const result;
  const json = JSON.parse(data);
    if (json.status === '') {
      json.status = 'Draft';
      result = JSON.stringify(json);
      return result;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

the syntax must be a little different

```
module.exports.verifyStandardMetadata = (data) => {
    const result;
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
      if (json.status === '') {
        json.status = 'Draft';
        result = JSON.stringify(json);
        return result;
      }
    };
```

Also you have to change the `result` from `const` to `let` as you are changing it

```
module.exports.verifyStandardMetadata = (data) => {
    let result;
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
      if (json.status === '') {
        json.status = 'Draft';
        result = JSON.stringify(json);
        return result;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your export syntax is wrong - `module.exports.verifyStandardMetadata(...)` would attempt to *call* a function, you want to *set* the function i.e.

```
module.exports.verifyStandardMetadata = data => {
  ....
}
```